# Tensorboard cannot show the graph

Tags: python, graph, tensorflow, tensorboard

I've already installed the latest version of Tensorflow (version_0.7), and I followed tutorial steps on training and testing mnist data, which was good. When I visualized the result using [Tensorboard](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/how_tos/summaries_and_tensorboard/index.html#tensorboard-visualizing-learning), I noticed that I could only see results for `Events` and `Histogram`, but except `Graph`... I tried different browsers including Safari, Chrome and Firefox, but nothing was showed for `Graph`. I am sure all code is correct, as I download the code from [website](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.7/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_with_summaries.py). and I also remembered that `Graph` on Tensorboard worked for Tensorflow version_0.6. I am wondering if there is wrong with the new version, or my setups. I really appreciate for any helps.

Comment: My colleague Daniel Smilkov has a suggestion for how to workaround this [on the GitHub issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1134#issuecomment-185279000), and it should be fixed in a bugfix release soon.